# how to send message once in a level Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Below is my script, Which is placed on my player bullet, each time my player fire, player bullet generate and after hitting at enemy or blockers it destroys, in this script I want when it send message for damage after that, it alarm other enemies, but only once in a level (every time player bullet generate, it will not alarm every time, just only once ), Here is my code. Advanced Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
public class player_bullet_mover : MonoBehaviour 
{
[HideInInspector]
public Vector3 target;
public GameObject target_object;
public float damage_is;
private player_damage_controller player_damage_script;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    player_damage_script = GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof(player_damage_controller)) as player_damage_controller;

    if(target == Vector3.zero)
    {
        Destroy(  this.gameObject );
    }
    transform.LookAt (target);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards ( this.transform.position , target, 300 * Time.deltaTime );
}

void OnTriggerEnter( Collider other )
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Enemy") )
    {
        other.SendMessage( "damage", 2 );
        Destroy( this.gameObject );
    }
    //call alarm_enemies function here but once in a level, not every time, it generate
}
public void alarm_enemies()
  {
    //send message to enemy script
  }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use [Collisions](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter) to detect when your bullet has hit an enemy and not do it like that in the update function.

Comment: Actually me whole project is designed in such a way, so cant change now because it will become messy for me. So next time I wiill keep this in mind

Comment: There is no next time. This is a **very bad** code. You have to start all over if it warrants it because there is no guarantee that the `if` statement will be true.

Comment: Ok, I am going to change my code and then will update my question.

Comment: OK, I had changed my code and update the question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you are using Unity's `SendMessage` function. Don't use that. You should do this with `delegate` and `event`.

Create an event in your `player_bullet_mover` script:

```
bool sentOnce = false;
public delegate void damaged();
public static event damaged OnDamaged;
```

In your `player_bullet_mover` script, call the functions subscribed to the event when there is a collision.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        other.SendMessage("damage", 2);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    //call alarm_enemies function here but once in a level, not every time, it generate

    //Send if we have not send this before
    if (!sentOnce)
    {
        sentOnce = true;
        //Alert every enemy
        OnDamaged();
    }
}
```

From your enemy script that you want to alert, subscribe to that event that is created in the  `player_bullet_mover` script. Subscribe to it in the `OnEnable` function and un-subscribe in the `OnDisable` function.

```
void OnEnable()
{
    player_bullet_mover.OnDamaged += damagedCallBack;
}


void OnDisable()
{
    player_bullet_mover.OnDamaged -= damagedCallBack;
}

void damagedCallBack()
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Damaged!");
}
```

You can learn more about this [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events).